# Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` that is assigned to several different listboxes.  I am trying to figure out when the `ContextMenuStrip` is clicked what `ListBox` it was used on.  I tried the code below as a start but it is not working.  The `sender` has the correct value, but when I try to assign it to the `menuSubmitted` it is null.

```
private void MenuViewDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu menuSubmitted = sender as ContextMenu;
    if (menuSubmitted != null)
    {
        Control sourceControl = menuSubmitted.SourceControl;
    }
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Using the assistance below, I figured it out:

```
private void MenuViewDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (menuItem != null)
            {
                ContextMenuStrip calendarMenu = menuItem.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;

                if (calendarMenu != null)
                {
                    Control controlSelected = calendarMenu.SourceControl;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution i was looking for. i had the same problem. but i suggest not nesting all those `if` statements and using `if (menuItem == null) return;` if you are like me and don't want your code that handles it to be nested an extra needless 2 levels.

Comment: It seems to me the solution you provide could be coded more concisely: `Control controlSelected = ((sender as ToolStripMenuItem)?.Owner as ContextMenuStrip)?.SourceControl;`

Answer (score 140, accepted):

### For a `ContextMenu`:

The problem is that the `sender` parameter points to the *item* on the context menu that was clicked, not the context menu itself.

It's a simple fix, though, because each `MenuItem` exposes a [`GetContextMenu` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.getcontextmenu.aspx) that will tell you which `ContextMenu` contains that menu item.

Change your code to the following:

```
private void MenuViewDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Try to cast the sender to a MenuItem
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem != null)
    {
        // Retrieve the ContextMenu that contains this MenuItem
        ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();

        // Get the control that is displaying this context menu
        Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;
    }
}
```

### For a `ContextMenuStrip`:

It does change things slightly if you use a `ContextMenuStrip` instead of a `ContextMenu`. The two controls are not related to one another, and an instance of one cannot be casted to an instance of the other.

As before, the *item* that was clicked is still returned in the `sender` parameter, so you will have to determine the `ContextMenuStrip` that owns this individual menu item. You do that with the [`Owner` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owner.aspx). Finally, you'll use the [`SourceControl` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx) to determine which control is displaying the context menu.

Modify your code like so:

```
private void MenuViewDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Try to cast the sender to a ToolStripItem
     ToolStripItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripItem;
     if (menuItem != null)
     {
        // Retrieve the ContextMenuStrip that owns this ToolStripItem
        ContextMenuStrip owner = menuItem.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
        if (owner != null)
        {
           // Get the control that is displaying this context menu
           Control sourceControl = owner.SourceControl;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: @bluefeet: Then you have something else wrong. I just tested this code with three different listboxes, and everything worked as expected. Post some more repro code.

Comment: @bluefeet: I've updated the code in my answer. There's a big difference between the `ContextMenu` and `ContextMenuStrip`. (Ah, and I see you've already figured it out. Well, all the better to learn things on your own!)

Comment: For a ToolStripItem you could do e.SelectedItem and that will return a ToolStripItem so casting is not necessary.

Comment: I used the Opening event to record the SourceControl that opened the menu to a local variable, and then referenced that when handling item clicks.

Comment: @QuickDanger Yeah, `SourceControl` is sadly null at the moment a `Click` event of a `ToolStripItem` sub-item of `ContextMenuStrip` is fired. It seems that the `ContextMenuStrip`'s `Closed` event fires _before_ that `Click` event, which is probably what causes the problem; I assume the property is cleared after the menu 'closes'.

Comment: @CodyGray Actually, if the tree is deeper you have to loop up the chain of `OwnerItem` properties until you find a `ToolStripItem` that has a `ContextMenuStrip` in its `Owner` property. But as I just commented, it doesn't work; the `SourceControl` on the context menu will be null. You said you can't reproduce it though... maybe the problem only occurs with menus deeper than one level? Mine was two sub-levels deep.

Comment: It might be a good idea to make something like this into an extension method

Comment: What if the menu item is activated via a keyboard shortcut?  The menu itself never opens, and the SourceControl is null.

Answer (score 5):

I had great difficulty getting any of this code to work.  This is the simplest solution I could find:

### For A ContextMenuStrip:

```
    Control _sourceControl = null;
    private void contextMenuStrip_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _sourceControl = contextMenuStrip.SourceControl;
    }

    private void contextMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        _sourceControl.Text = menuItem.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(menuItem.Name);
        MessageBox.Show(sourceControl.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Older post, but in case someone like myself comes across it:

For a ContextMenuStrip, the above didn't work for me, but it led to finding what did.

```
void DeleteMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenuStrip menu = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
    Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;
    MessageBox.Show(sourceControl.Name);
}
```

This gave me the expected control's name. You can put in validation etc with if statements, I'm just posting to get to the point.

Comment: This only works with the _direct_ items in a `ContextMenu`. The problem is that `ItemClicked` doesn't fire when clicking _sub-menu items_; they need their own `Click` event which would have the item itself as sender, not the menu.

Answer (score 3):

Cast sender to ToolStripItem to reach Owner which will be a ToolStrip that doesn't have a SourceControl property.

Cast Owner to ContextMenuStrip to reach SourceControl.

```
Control sc = ((ContextMenuStrip)((ToolStripItem)sender).Owner).SourceControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just using ActiveForm.ActiveControl, in this example from a C1 grid:

```
C1.Win.FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid fg = frmMain.ActiveForm.ActiveControl as C1.Win.FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be:

```
Control parentControl = ((sender as MenuItem).GetContextMenu()).SourceControl;
```