# Getting dynamically created item's text when right-clicked

Tags: vb.net

I have some dynamically create labels with a context menu strip. When you right click the label it give you a context menu strip. How can I get their text when I click an item in their context menu strip? I know this is a really simple question but I need some help.
I've tried

```
Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        MsgBox(sender.Text)
End Sub
```

I'm trying to get the text of the label that generated the contextmenustrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for which control fired the context menu, something like this:

```
Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click

  Dim menuItem As ToolStripItem = TryCast(sender, ToolStripItem)
  If menuItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim owner As ContextMenuStrip = TryCast(menuItem.Owner, ContextMenuStrip)
    If owner IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim sourceControl As Control = owner.SourceControl
      MessageBox.Show(sourceControl.Text)
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Converted to VB.Net from [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886417/719186)

Comment: I'm trying to get the text of the `label`, not the `contextmenustrip`. Will this work for that...?

Comment: @Gordan What is FileItem?  A label or a menu item?

Comment: FileItem is a label. I'll change around the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Gordan In that case, just cast it to a Label.  Updated answer.

Comment: Does it make a difference that the label is created programmatically? And there are more than one?

Comment: @Gordan I updated the answer with what I think is causing the issue.  The sender is your menu item, so you need to find which label showed the context menu.