# Determine which PictureBox is clicked by mouse from ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some dynamically created `PictureBox`'s and a `ContextMenu` with a `ToolStripMenuItem` named "Remove" ... I want to remove only the `PictureBox` that is clicked but this `ContextMenu` is attached to all `PictureBox`'s.

How to do it ? And please explain because I am still a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to follow the chain of menu owners until you get to the control:

```
private void RemoveMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ToolStripMenuItem ti = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
  ContextMenuStrip cs = ti.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
  PictureBox pb = cs.SourceControl as PictureBox;
  MessageBox.Show(pb.Name);  // or pb.Dispose();
}
```

This code isn't doing any error checking.  You should check to see if any of those variables are null before trying to access any of its properties.

Cody Gray gave a comprehensive answer here: [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886417/719186)