# How to check which DataGrid has fired a event in ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've create a ContexMenu, and the option allow the user to clear the all item in the DataGrid. All working so good, but I want to optimize the algorithm with one method, in particular I want do this:

1. User go in one of three DataGrid and press right mouse button, delete the option in this table
2. A method starting the method, this method should do this:

   - Check which table has fired the events, get the DataGrid name and delete all rows of the DataGrid that have fired the events.
     This is my code XAML CODE:

     ```
     ContextMenu x:Key="Squadre_ContextMenu">
         <MenuItem Header="Pulisci Tabella" Click="ClearTable_Click">
         </MenuItem>
     </ContextMenu>
     ```

**C# CODE method calling:**

```
private void ClearTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((DataGrid)sender).Name.ToString()); //exception returned...
        //datagrid.ClearValue();
    }
```

and in a class I've the property function:

```
 public static void removeRows(DataGrid name passed by parameter)
    {
        var grid = parameter passed;
        var mygrid = parameter passed;

        if (grid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            for (int i = grid.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                mygrid.Items.Remove(grid.SelectedItems[i]);
            };
        }

        grid = mygrid;
    }
```

NB: datagrid variable is an instance of the class DataGrid datagrid = new DataGrid(); this class contains the function for delete all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother passing the name of the grid? Why not just pass the grid itself to the function and operate on it that way?

```
    private void ClearDataGrid(DataGrid aDataGrid)
    {
        // clear aDataGrid's contents here
    }
```

Just call the function, and pass the DataGrid you want to clear to it.

You can use the following information to determine what control was clicked on:

[Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on)

Comment: I've multiple DataGrid on the UI, I don't know which DataGrid has start the event..

Comment: I updated my answer. Check out this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on

Comment: ContextMenu is also covered in that link.