# Missing library for ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a code for get the name of the control that fire the ContextMenu, but the compiler return this message on this line: `ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();`

> MenuItem does not contain a definition of GetContextMenu and found no extension method 'GetContextMenu' accepting a first argument of type 'MenuItem'. Probably missing a using directive or an assembly reference.

The same error here:

```
Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;
```

This is my method:

```
private void ClearTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Try to cast the sender to a MenuItem
        MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            // Retrieve the ContextMenu that contains this MenuItem
            ContextMenu menu = menuItem.GetContextMenu();

            // Get the control that is displaying this context menu
            Control sourceControl = menu.SourceControl;
        }
    }
```

Which library I must to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.GetContextMenu()` is a method of the `Menu` class in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (in System.Windows.Forms.dll). Therefore it's not designed to work on WPF controls... although with some tweaking it may be possible.

If you're doing this in WPF, you'll want to use `ContextMenu` class in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace, with its methods.

Comment: I've used: ContextMenu menuItem = sender as ContextMenu; but same error returned..

Comment: ContextMenu exists as a class in both namespaces I listed in my error, so `ContextMenu menuItem = sender as ContextMenu;` would work. The trouble is, your code is now using the `ContextMenu` in `System.Windows.Controls` namespace - which does not have a `.GetContextMenu()` method.

Comment: Okay, but there's an alternative method to GetContextMenu();?

Comment: I want just get the name of the control that has fired an event through ContextMenu, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on

Comment: Yep, so that is definitely outside the scope of this question, but off the top of my head I'm thinking of using something like the `Parent` property of the sender argument.

Comment: I've another question opened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on
If you want take a look, thanks.

Comment: okay. if you think my answer answered this question, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Okay, could you help me in the another question, please?