# C# Selecting text from the correct textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have an Windows Form app with multiple Textboxes. I'm trying to add a right-click copy & paste function into it. I have added the right-click menu by using the ContextMenuStrip. However, I'm using this menu for 2 different textboxes in the app. When I select and highlight some text from 1 text box and then do the same thing by selecting and highlighting text from the other textbox, it copies in the text from both textboxes. How do I separate it so that it knows which textbox to copy from?

This is the code I have:

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string leadSelectedText = leadsTextBox.SelectedText;
            string resultSelectedText = resultTextBox.SelectedText;

            Console.WriteLine(leadSelectedText);
            Console.WriteLine(resultSelectedText);
        }
```

Comment: Why did you tell about the ContextMenuStrip, but show us a copyToolStripMenuItem_Click method?

Comment: because that's the Item within that Context Menu??

Comment: Sorry, look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine which textbox the mouse is over you could try the following.

```
        if (leadsTextBox == GetChildAtPoint(MousePosition))
        {
            //copy from leads text
        }
        else if (resultTextBox == GetChildAtPoint(MousePosition))
        {
            //copy from results text
        }
```

If the mouse doesn't have to be over the textbox to copy, you could always store which textbox was last clicked.

```
Textbox lastClicked;

private void leadsTextbox_mouseDown()
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(leadsTextbox.SelectText))
       lastClicked = leadsTextbox;
}
```

Comment: I think when the user click menu item, the mouse cursor may not be over the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ActiveControl` to get the currently active textbox. 
You would first have to click into this textbox to activate it. 
But If you just select text and then right-click this will do.

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Windows.Forms.Control control = this.ActiveControl;
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox))
            System.Console.WriteLine(((System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)control).SelectedText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this,

```
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TextBox> box = new List<TextBox>();
        box = pMainScreen.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c => c.Name.Contains("")).ToList();

        foreach(TextBox b in box)
        {
            if (b.SelectionLength > 0)
                label7.Text = b.Text;
        }
    }
```

So here are few things about this function,
~This will identify the textbox where the text had been previously highlighted
~Issue:  It is possible that more than one textbox can have highlighted text at a time, so it will only identify the last one it hits in the loop

You'll need to add some validation ontop of this, but I'm pretty sure this does what your OP describe.
-Also it will be `Console.WriteLine(b.Text);` for your program.
-All my controls were inside a panel called `pMainScreen`, you can use `this.controls.oftype.blahblah` instead to identify your textboxes.