# Apply same contextmenustrip to more textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, textbox, contextmenustrip

Is there a way to apply the same contextmenustrip to more textboxes?
I have a WinForm with 6 textboxes and I want my context menu strip to clear the context of a texbox.

```
private void stergeContinutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_cnp.Clear();
    }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to change the code so that the contextmenustrip works on every textbox in my form. (I mean, on a generic textbox)

I want to avoid writing the same code for 6 contextmenustrips. Thanks!

Comment: What about just attaching the same event... on the designer... go to events and paste the one that you have to all content strips.

Comment: Are you asking to loop through all your controls to find all the TextBoxes, or how to attach the same menu strip to all the TextBoxes?

Comment: Exactly @LarsTech.

Comment: Exactly what?  I'm still confused what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidEspino I've tried youe solution, but unfortunately it does not work. No matter where I apply the contextmenustrip, only the content of the textbox invocated in the code of the contextmenustrip is deleted. But thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @LarsTech , I want to have just one contextmenustrip and apply its functionality to every textbox in my form. It should clear the content of a textbox, no matter which textbox it is.

Comment: It should strip to all the textboxes.

Comment: `textBox1.ContextMenuStrip = yourMenu; textBox2.ContextMenuStrip = yourMenu;` etc, etc.

Comment: Check out this thread for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on