# Is there a way to know which TreeNode is right clicked after one of its ContextMenuStrip items is left clicked and the item's CheckedState changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, contextmenustrip, toolstripmenu

**Update on 5/10/2018**. orhtej2 suggested that my question might be a dup of [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on). It is **almost** a dup, but my scenario has one significant difference. See my modified question and my answer for details.

See my code below. My goal is more cleanly determine which TreeNode is right-clicked after one of its ContextMenuItems is left clicked.

As it is now, when I right-click one of the two child nodes, the `if` statement in the `TreeView1_NodeMouseClick` loads the clicked `TreeNode` into the global `treeViewClickedNode` `TreeNode` object. Then, when I left click one of the two `contextMenuStripChildNode` `ToolStripMenuItem`, the `DocumentActionToolStripMenuItem_CheckStateChanged` method is fired. I can then examine the check state. If its checked, I can then do something to the `treeViewClickedNode` `TreeNode`.

My question: Is there a cleaner way to determine which TreeNode is right clicked after one of its ContextMenuStrip items is left clicked, i.e., is there a way to do away with the global variable `treeViewClickedNode`?

Note: The only thing I did in the designer was to place `treeview1` on `Form1`, dock it to `Form1` and set 'treeview1' `NodeMouseClick` to `TreeView1_NodeMouseClick`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp_Scratch
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TreeNode treeViewClickedNode;
        ContextMenu mnu = new ContextMenu();

        public Form1()        
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create the root node.
            TreeNode treeNodeRoot = new TreeNode("Documents");

            // Add the root node to the TreeView.
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNodeRoot);

            //Create and add child 2 nodes each with a two item ContextMenuStrip.
            string[] childNodeLabels = { "document1.docx", "document2.docx"};
            string[] contextItemLabels = { "Action A", "Action B" };

            foreach (String childNodeLabel in childNodeLabels)
            {
                TreeNode treeNode = treeNodeRoot.Nodes.Add(childNodeLabel);

                // Create a ContextMenuStrip for this child node.
                ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStripChildNode = new ContextMenuStrip
                {
                    ShowCheckMargin = true,
                    ShowImageMargin = false
                };

                foreach (String contextItemLabel in contextItemLabels)
                {
                    //Create a menu item.
                    ToolStripMenuItem action = new ToolStripMenuItem(contextItemLabel, null, DocumentActionToolStripMenuItem_CheckStateChanged)
                    {
                        CheckOnClick = true
                    };

                    contextMenuStripChildNode.Items.Add(action);
                }

                treeNode.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStripChildNode;
            }


        private void TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeView t = (TreeView)sender;
            //Force the node that was right-clicked to be selected
            t.SelectedNode = t.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                treeViewClickedNode = e.Node;
            }
        }

        private void DocumentActionToolStripMenuItem_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

            if (toolStripMenuItem.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                //Do something with treeViewClickedNode object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on)

Comment: @orhtej2: **Almost** a dup. See change I made to my question and my answer (that is based on the S.O. question [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `For a ContextMenuStrip` portion of the answer for S.O. question [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on) **almost** answers my question.

In my case, however, I want to process the `ContextMenuStrip` item right-click and access the `ContextMenuStrip` item's `CheckState` when the `CheckState` changes, so my code uses a `ContextMenuStrip` item `_CheckStateChanged` event method instead of a `ContextMenuStrip` item `_Click` event method. As such, I need to cast the sender to a `ToolStripMenuItem` instead of a  `ToolStripItem`. Other than that, I use the `For a ContextMenuStrip` portion of the answer from the S.O. question [Determine what control the ContextMenuStrip was used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886327/determine-what-control-the-contextmenustrip-was-used-on) in my `DocumentActionToolStripMenuItem_CheckStateChanged` event method :

```
private void DocumentActionToolStripMenuItem_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control treeNodeControl;

    ToolStripMenuItem toolStripMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

    // if the ToolStripMenuItem item is owned by a ContextMenuStrip ...
    if (toolStripMenuItem.Owner is ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip)
    {
        // Get the TreeNode that is displaying this context menu
        treeNodeControl = contextMenuStrip.SourceControl;

        if (toolStripMenuItem.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            //Do something with treeNodeControl.SelectedNode treeView node
        }
    }

}
```